# What is the advantage of putting `data-` before reference to Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been learning angular in part through [this video](https://youtu.be/i9MHigUZKEM). At several points the narrator mentions that he prefers placing `data-` before references to angular directives in HTML templates, e.g., `<div data-ng-app="...">`, `<div data-ng-init="...">`, etc. However, he doesn't explain this preference.

My question is: what is is the advantage/effect of preceding angular directives with `data-` in this way?

Comment: Best Practice: Prefer using the **dash-delimited format** (e.g. ng-bind for ngBind). If you want to use an **HTML validating tool**, you can instead use the data-prefixed version (e.g. data-ng-bind for ngBind). The other forms shown above are accepted for legacy reasons but we advise you to avoid them.

[https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only advantage is to have a valid HTML.